# magento 2 update error - uncommited changes

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to update magento-2 from 2.1.9 to 2.2.
I get the following error:

> Source directory /chroot/home/minimoon/staging.ochosbags.com/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib has uncommitted changes.

How can I fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not run composer in non-interactive mode, it should give you some options:

- discard changes
- stash changes
- view changes
- abort

If you are sure, you did not change anything in `vendor`, you can discard the changes. It might be something irrelevant like changed file permissions.

If you DID change something (which you should never do) and you want to keep the changes, try "stash". The changes will be saved, and git will try to re-apply them after the update.

If you are not sure, view the changes and then decide.

Comment: it's non-interactive mode.
How do I run in in interactive mode?

Comment: Composer on the command line is interactive by default, it's only non-interactive if you pass the `-n` or `--no-interaction` parameter. But it might be that the environment variable  `COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION` is set. Then you can unset it for one command: `COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION=0 composer update`. Or are you using the web installer instead of composer?

Comment: By the way, here's the documentation for these parameters: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-no-interaction

Comment: ohh I see now.
Yes I'm using the web installer. Should I use the command line to install?

Comment: Yes, in the web installer there's no interactive mode.